# I have been asked to make an Create a new integer array with 16 elements

Tags: java, arrays, user-input

Java code (not Java script). I was asked to create a new integer array with 16 elements.

Only integers between 1 and 7 are to be entered in the array from user (scanner)input.

Only valid user input should be permitted, and any integers entered outside the bounds (i.e. < 1 or > 7 should be excluded and a warning message displayed.
Design a program that will sort the array.

The program should display the contents of the sorted array.
The program should then display the numbers of occurrences of each number chosen by user input
however i have been trying to complete this code step by step and used my knowledge to help me but need help my current code is under I would appreciate if some one is able to edit my code into the above wants.I know it needs to enter the array by user input store and reuse the code to sort the numbers into sort the array.

The result should print out something like this like this
“The numbers entered into the array are:” 1, 2,4,5,7
“The number you chose to search for is” 7 
“This occurs” 3 “times in the array”

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class test20 {

   public static void main (String[] args){


      Scanner userInput = new Scanner (System.in);

      int [] nums = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,6,6,2,7,7,1,4,5,6};

      int count = 0;    
      int input = 0;


      boolean isNumber = false;

      do {

            System.out.println ("Enter a number to check in the array");

            if (userInput.hasNextInt()){

                 input = userInput.nextInt();
                 System.out.println ("The number you chose to search for is " + input);
                 isNumber = true;

             }else { 
                        System.out.println ("Not a proper number");
                   }


                 for (int i = 0; i< nums.length; i++){      
                     if (nums [i]==input){
                         count ++;              
                 }

             }

             System.out.println("This occurs " + count + " times in the array");

        }

        while (!(isNumber));

    }
    private static String count(String string) {
      return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't post code without proper indentation. You are asking people for help; you could at least make your code readable.

Comment: sorry was a rush job typing ..long story wont happen again

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please edit your question to actually ask one. What is your difficulty with the code above? Is there an error. If so, please add it. Please go through the tour for new users and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class test20 {

  private static int readNumber(Scanner userInput) {
    int nbr;

    while (true) {
      while(!userInput.hasNextInt()) {
        System.out.println("Enter valid integer!");
        userInput.next();
      }

      nbr = userInput.nextInt();

      if (nbr >= 1 && nbr <= 7) {
        return nbr;
      } else {
        System.out.println("Enter number in range 1 to 7!");
      }
    }
  }

  private static int count(int input, int[] nums) {
    int count = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++){
      if (nums[i] == input){
        count++;
      } else if (nums[i] > input) {
        break;
      }
    }

    return count;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);

    int[] nums = new int[16];

    for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
      nums[i] = readNumber(userInput);
    }

    Arrays.sort(nums);
    System.out.println ("Sorted numbers: " + Arrays.toString(nums));

    int input = 0;

    while(true) {

      System.out.println("Search for a number in array");

      input = readNumber(userInput);
      System.out.println("The number you chose to search for is " + input);

      System.out.println("This occurs " + 
        count(input, nums) + " times in the array");
    }
  }
}
```

Because the array is sorted, I break the loop if an element larger than the one we're looking for is found; if we encounter a larger one then no other matches can be found in the rest of the array.

Comment: thank you both of you.I'll study the code so i do not make the same mistakes again and have a good day or night